RISC-V Fixed Point Arithmetic
I have following problem:
I wanted to add two numbers -1.25 and 3.25 (the result is obviously 2) in RISC-V assembly using 32-bit registers.
I assumed Q format (imaginary decimal point), so that there would be 29 integer positions (I know that is not necessary and I can have better resolution with allocating more positions to fractional part, but this is just for simplicity) and 3 fractional positions in U2 format.
So I converted -1.25 in dec to bin (U2) (wihout imaginary decimal point):
11111111111111111111111111111110.110

And 3.25:
00000000000000000000000000000011.010

And then converted it to HEX in order to store it in my program.
My code is:
.data
    newLine: .asciz "\n"
    num: .word 0xFFFFFFFEC 
    num2: .word 0x000000034
.text
    li a7, 4
    la a0, newLine
    ecall
    
    la t5, num
    lw t5, 0(t5)

    la t6, num2
    lw t6, 0(t6)
    
    add t3, t5, t6
    
    li a7, 4
    la a0, newLine
    ecall
    
    li a7, 35
    mv a0, t3
    ecall

And in the end I get:
00000000000000000000000000100000

What I've got is 32 in dec and I'm very confused.
Because I thought that if I have 3 slots after the decimal point it means that if, at the end, I shift right the result by 3 bits I would get the integer part. But for the moment if I shift my result by 3 bits I would get:
00000000000000000000000000000100

Which is 4, not 2.
Why doesn't it work that way?
Also I have another question:
How to print the result in RARS simulator so that I would have this result in my desired format? For example if I would add 3.33 and 1.50 I would get: 4.83. I know how to get the integer part (by shifting certain amount of bits) but don't know how to do it for fractional part.
Thank you in advance.

Your hex conversions don't match your binary values - they seem to have 4 bits after the decimal point, rather than 3.

0.110₂ = 0x6; 1010₂ = 0xA


I know how to get the integer part (by shifting certain amount of bits) but don't know how to do it for fractional part.

With just the fraction bits, multiply by 1/(2^N)*(10^M), where N is the number of fraction bits and M is the number of decimal places to print.  (Be sure to print leading zeros.)
So for 3 fraction bits, multiply them by 1/(2^3)×10^3 = 0.125×1000 aka by 125, will give values 0, 125, 250, 375, 500, 625, 750, or 875.
In 4 bits, the idea is that the fraction 0001₂ represents 1/16, which is 0.0625.  So that's 4 digits of fraction in decimals.  Multiply the fraction bits e.g. 0001₂ by 0.0625×10000 i.e. by 625 and print 4 digits: 0625.
Be sure to print sufficient leading 0's.  Here, 0000₂ = 0/16 needs 4 zeros, whereas 0001₂ = 1/16 needs 1 initial zero, though 0010₂ = 2/16 or greater do not require leading zeros.

Let's look at 8 fractional bits.  00000001₂ represents 1/(2^8)=1/256=0.00390625.  We'll need 8 decimal digits for that so our conversion factor becomes 390625. 100000000₂ × 390625 = 50000000, i.e. 0.5 or 1/2.

To put it all together, print the integer value, then print a decimal point, then any needed initial zeros, and finally the fractional portion having been multiplied by the factor of above calculation to become an integer.
(Negative numbers are left as an exercise.)

Could you provide some snippet in risc-v assembly code? It would be very helpful

@wojtek5739g, Compute the specific factor for the number of fraction bits on paper — it will be a constant, then all you have to do is multiply the fraction by this pre-computed constant factor.  FYI, assembly is not required for fixed point arithmetic & printing, all can be done in C, for example. where you can inspect compiler output if you like.
